ReactNativePaper configureFonts invalid typescript for ThemeFonts
I'm using
"react-native-paper": "^4.12.8",

and I'm trying to configure the theme:
declare global {
  namespace ReactNativePaper {
    interface ThemeColors {
      textInverted: string;
    }

    interface ThemeFonts {
      otherType: Font;
      anotherType: Font;
    }
  }
}

const fontFamily: ReactNativePaper.ThemeFonts = {
  regular: {
    fontFamily: 'SomeFont',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
  medium: {
    fontFamily: 'SomeFont',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
  light: {
    fontFamily: 'SomeFont',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
  thin: {
    fontFamily: 'SomeFont',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
  otherType: {
    fontFamily: 'SomeFont',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
  anotherType: {
    fontFamily: 'SomeFont',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
};

const fontConfig = {
  ios: {...fontFamily},
  android: {...fontFamily},
  default: {...fontFamily},
};

export const theme: ReactNativePaper.Theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  fonts: configureFonts(fontConfig),
};

and in react-native-paper in fonts.d.ts there is
export default function configureFonts(config?: {
    [platform in PlatformOSType | 'default']?: Fonts;
}): Fonts;

which indicates that it returns Fonts (not ThemeFonts) and it takes Fonts (not ThemeFonts) as parameter yet typescript doesn't bother the mismatch in types for parameter but it is mad of the return type:
error TS2739: Type 'Fonts' is missing the following properties from type 'ThemeFonts': otherType, anotherType

fonts: configureFonts(fontConfig),
~~~~~

it works when I do
fonts: configureFonts(fontConfig) as ReactNativePaper.ThemeFonts,

but adding as often indicates that sth is wrong
